# Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908) ubuntu 16.04

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, virtualbox-networking

I have seen that there are many questions in this regard but I have not gotten any of the proposed solutions to work with my setting. Although I have secureboot enabled.

I tried the following commands with no success:

But towards the end of number 3, there appears to be a problem that pointed to the following code.

```
virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-09-07 16:27:35 GMT; 2min 45s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1135 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/virtualbox start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 07 16:27:35 HP-PC systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
Sep 07 16:27:35 HP-PC virtualbox[1135]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
Sep 07 16:27:35 HP-PC virtualbox[1135]:  * modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out
Sep 07 16:27:35 HP-PC virtualbox[1135]:    ...fail!
Sep 07 16:27:35 HP-PC systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 07 16:27:35 HP-PC systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
Sep 07 16:27:35 HP-PC systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 07 16:27:35 HP-PC systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Ultimately I am not able to run virtual machines.